# Необходимость точки с запятой после блоков в java

Tags: java, синтаксис, linux

Нужно ли ставить точку с запятой в конце блока после фигурной скобки в java? (ставил раньше иногда - теперь задумался об необходимости) Более всего интересуют блоки `if` и `for`

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от типа блока. Например после блока когда (инициализатора класса и др.) не нужно, после объявления анонимного класса нужно.

Comment: @misha-nesterenko Более всего интересуют блоки `if` и `for`

Comment: там собственно то и блоки не обязательны. Точка с запятой после блока тоже не обязательна.

Answer (score 0):

1. Точка с запятой обозначает конец выражения
2. Фигурная скобка сама по себе не является выражением - она лишь группирует выражения

Следствия отсюда:

1. Если закрывающаяся фигурная скобка не означает конец выражения, то после нее точка с запятой не ставится - например: `if (a>0) {b=1;}` и проч.
2. В противном случае ставится: например объявление анонимного класса, инициализация массива (`String[] array = new String[]{"hello", "world"};`) и проч.